# Why is creating shared_ptr from unique_ptr of array not allowed anymore?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, language-design

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

> In C++11 and C++14 it is valid to construct a `std::shared_ptr<T>` from
>   a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`:
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[1]);
> std::shared_ptr<int> ptr(std::move(arr));
> ```
>
> Since the `shared_ptr` obtains its deleter (a
>   `std::default_delete<T[]>` object) from the `unique_ptr`, the array will
>   be correctly deallocated.
>
> This is no longer allowed in C++17. Instead the array form
>   `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` should be used.

Why is it not allowed in C++17? What has changed?

Comment: Some readings if you want: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0414r2.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[p0497r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0497r0.html):

> **Incorrect constraint for shared_ptr construction from unique_ptr**
>
> [...]
>
> Based on implementation experience I believe the correct form is:
>
> *Remark:* This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `Y*` is compatible with `T*` and `unique_ptr<Y, D>::pointer` is convertible to `element_type*`.
>
> The "compatible with" check prevents undesirable conversions from `unique_ptr<T[]>` to `shared_ptr<T>` and the "convertible to" check ensures that the result of `unique_ptr<Y, D>::get()` can be stored in the `shared_ptr` and returned by `shared_ptr<T>::get()`.

In other words, this was intentionally made invalid just because it shouldn't be valid, not simply a side effect of other changes.

Which makes sense to me. `shared_ptr<T>` is likely to be read by other programmers as pointing to only one `T` object. Requiring programmers to use `shared_ptr<T[]>` when they want multiple `T` objects leads to more readable code.

<sub>Note: this correct form is not in the standard. The rationale, however, is in part a comment on what is in the standard.</sub>

Comment: I think it is reasonable that `unique_ptr<T[]>` should not be converted into `shared_ptr<T>`. But is it worth breaking backward-compatibility?

Comment: @ikh Keep in mind that originally, there were *no* checks at all, this meant that generic code couldn't use SFINAE to check that implicitly converting `std::unique_ptr<int>` to `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` is nonsense. (`static_assert(std::is_convertible<std::unique_ptr<std::string>, std::shared_ptr<int>>(), "");` was required to pass.) If the wording is adjusted to correct this, yes, I think it's worth getting it right straight away.

Comment: @ikh also the shared ptr aliasing constructor is a workaround if we need that particular conversion.  Like `auto tmp=shared_ptr<T[]>( std::move(up) ); auto sp=shared_ptr<T>( tmp.get(), tmp  );`